# How to implement your own catch errors in JS class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a JS Promise implementation and getting a little lost. I want to implement the newbie version of promises.

I am creating a class and set the resolve and reject methods as private. Then created a empty callback function and use it to call when resolve or rejected the results.

```
class MyPromise {
    
    constructor(initFunction) {
        this.cb = () => {};
        initFunction(this.#resolve.bind(this), this.#reject.bind(this));
    }

    #resolve(value) {
        this.cb(value)
    }

    #reject(value) {
        this.cb(value)
    }

    then(cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
    }
```

I made than a small simulation of add function :

```
const add = (a, b) => {
    return new MyPromise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') 
                reject('Invalid params')
            else 
                resolve(a + b);
        }, 1000);

    })
}
```

The then method works somehow, but I am not able to create the catch method.

```
add(2, 5).then(result => console.log(result))
// .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

What would be your steps?

Comment: Your `then` function have to return a new promise

Comment: You are, and I mean no offense (they aren't the most intuitive thing to grok), way off-track here: that's not at all how Promises work. You might find this interesting reading: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2020/09/creating-javascript-promise-from-scratch-constructor/

Comment: `then` should not be called in the reject case, if you're recreating promises. [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) is the specification...

Comment: @JaredSmith so this is not an advanced topic? My teacher gave me this to solve. If I can. I am not able

Comment: "so this is not an advanced topic?" it actually kinda **is** an advanced topic. I don't want to sound judgy without more background context, but that's hardly a task _I_ would give to a novice programmer. Either way you'll want to implement the spec that Heretic Monkey linked to rather than try to wing it, and if your not used to reading specs... well, I guess it's not the _worst_ one to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You must return "this" from the "then" method to be able to chain the methods calls, and use another callback.
But as the other comments said, async/await is a complex subject implemented "inside" the languages.

```js
class MyPromise {

    constructor(initFunction) {
        this.cb = () => {};
        this.catch_cb = () => {};
        initFunction(this.#resolve.bind(this), this.#reject.bind(this));
    }

    #resolve(value) {
        this.cb(value)
    }

    #reject(value) {
        this.catch_cb(value)
    }

    then(cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
        return this;
    }

    catch(cb) {
      this.catch_cb = cb;
    }
}

const add = (a, b) => {
    return new MyPromise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number')
                reject('Invalid params')
            else
                resolve(a + b);
        }, 1000);

    })
}

add("plop", 5).then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```